# Python versatile Index slicing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, data-modeling, data-cleaning

Hoping someone can help me with the logic of transforming this Excel logic to python

```
=IF(LEFT(A8,5)="Total",A9,I8)
```

So I am looking to find everything in a range and then creating a new column with the first element in the range. The problem is that the names of the ranges can change.

A current solution I have implemented is converting a column to the index, and by manually selecting by index names by doing the following:

```
Sales = df.loc['1000 - Cash and Equivalents':'Total - 1000 - Cash and Equivalents']
```

The problem this name may change and may contain fewer or more rows, and need to make this more versatile, so I can not specify a numbered range.

*This is an example of the data:*

[image]

*and Post transformation I have the data looking like the following*:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain if your solution `Sales = df.loc['1000 - Cash and Equivalents':'Total - 1000 - Cash and Equivalents']` is not possible use, what is expected input? String `1000` ? or `Cash and Equivalents` Or something else?

Comment: Yea sure, so I have made the Accounts column the index in pandas and sliced by index name

Comment: Yes, it understand, but not sure what do you want. My excel knowledge is poor, also I have no your excel data, so hard to test and guess what need by `=IF(LEFT(A8,5)="Total",A9,I8)`

Comment: @jezrael to be clear up this is what code I have working now, https://pastebin.com/51FHMyfj 
I hope you can see from this what I am aiming to achieve

Comment: it is better, is `PL.csv` confidental?

Comment: @jezrael Yes unfortunately, I created dummy information here
https://files.fm/u/5f8zg5q2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('PL2.csv', encoding='cp1252', engine='python')


#create helper df for total strings
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0].str.startswith('Total', na=False), df.columns[0]].to_frame('total')
#first column without Total - 
df1['first'] = df1['total'].str.replace('Total - ', '')
print (df1.head(10))
                                    total                          first
17                   Total - 4000 - Sales                   4000 - Sales
21  Total - 4200 - Discounts & Allowances  4200 - Discounts & Allowances
24       Total - 4400 - Excise and Duties       4400 - Excise and Duties
25                          Total - Sales                          Sales
37      Total - 5000 - Cost of Goods Sold      5000 - Cost of Goods Sold

#create index by first column
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])

#filter function - if not matched return empty df
def get_dict(df, first, last):
    try:
        df = df.loc[first: last]
        df['Sub-Category'] = first
    except KeyError:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df

#in dictionary comprehension create dict of DataFrames     
d = {k: get_dict(df, k, v) for k, v in zip(df1['first'], df1['total'])}
#print (d)

#select Sales df
print (d['Sales'])
```